# Get position item after search functionality from ListView - Android

Tags: java, android

Here i have a parsed json data from url and adding into listview with search functionality , When get an item by search functionality setOnItemClickListener don't get correct and position item from listview , but OnItemClick without search functionality is working good.

```
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                final JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                final String fname = json_data.getString("fname");
                final String lname = json_data.getString("lname");
                final String username = json_data.getString("username");
                final String gender = json_data.getString("gender");

                HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                contact.put("fname", fname);
                contact.put("lname", lname);
                contact.put("username", username);
                contact.put("gender", gender);
                users.add(contact);

                simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(SearchActivity.this, users,
                        R.layout.list_search_item, new String[]{"fname","lname"},
                        new int[]{R.id.fname,R.id.lname});
                lv.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);

                lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

                Search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                        SearchActivity.this.simpleAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                    }
                });

                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent , View view , int position , long id){
                        Intent i = new Intent(SearchActivity.this,UserProfileActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("fname",users.get(position).get("fname"));
                        i.putExtra("lname",users.get(position).get("lname"));
                        i.putExtra("username",users.get(position).get("username"));
                        i.putExtra("gender",users.get(position).get("gender"));
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });

            }
```

Comment: use `Adapter#getItem()`

Comment: Didn't work too

Comment: why do you say that it didnt work? it works as expected

Comment: tell me how to do it exactly

Comment: i already did: call `Adapter#getItem()` inside `onItemClick`

Comment: You are setting adapter everytime you get a new object. Set you adapter to list view outside. Actually you should set adapter, filter, and TextWatcher outside. Then apply changes to adapter, add notifyDatasetChange after that.

Comment: could you give me an example about notifyDatasetChange or about what i want

Comment: you dont need any `notifyDatasetChange` just use `getItem` and call both `setAdapeter` and `addTextChangedListener` outside your `for` loop

Comment: I get it , it's work , thanks alot